# Reading drools rules in rest java

Tags: java, rest, drools, rules

I'm trying to read .drl drools rules in my REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey.

I put my .drl files in WEB-INF/rules folder, and tried to read them with this lines of code

```
private RuleBase trainingRules;
private RuleBase kuperMaleTrainingResultsRules;
private RuleBase kuperFemaleTrainingResultsRules;
private RuleBase basicTrainingResultsRules;

private final String trainingRulesPath = "/WEB-INF/rules/ZatraziTrening.drl";
private final String kuperMaleTrainingResultsPath = "/WEB-INF/rules/KuperMuski.drl";
private final String kuperFemaleTrainingResultsPath = "/WEB-INF/rules/KuperZenski.drl";
private final String trainingResultsRulesPath = "/WEB-INF/rules/RezultatiTreninga.drl";

private static ControllerDrools INSTANCE;

private ControllerDrools() {
    try {
        this.trainingRules = loadRules(trainingRulesPath);
        this.kuperMaleTrainingResultsRules = loadRules(kuperMaleTrainingResultsPath);
        this.kuperFemaleTrainingResultsRules = loadRules(kuperFemaleTrainingResultsPath);
        this.basicTrainingResultsRules = loadRules(trainingResultsRulesPath);
    } catch (DroolsParserException | IOException e) {
        // TODO: dodati ispis poruke u logger
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private RuleBase loadRules(String rulesPath) throws DroolsParserException, IOException {
    Reader source = new InputStreamReader(ControllerDrools.class.getResourceAsStream(rulesPath));

    PackageBuilder builder = new PackageBuilder();

    builder.addPackageFromDrl(source);

    Package pkg = builder.getPackage();

    // Kreiranje baze znanja i dodavanje paketa u nju
    RuleBase ruleBase = RuleBaseFactory.newRuleBase();
    ruleBase.addPackage(pkg);
    return ruleBase;
}

public static ControllerDrools getInstance() {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        INSTANCE = new ControllerDrools();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

/**
 * Get's the training from drools
 * @param user
 * @return training to do
 */
public Training getTrening(User user) {

    user.setNumberOfTrainingInCategory(user.getNumberOfTrainingInCategory() + 1);

    Training training = new Training();
    training.setUser(user);

    try {
        WorkingMemory workingMemory = trainingRules.newStatefulSession();

        workingMemory.insert(user);
        workingMemory.insert(training);
        workingMemory.insert(user.getCategory());

        workingMemory.fireAllRules();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: logger
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return training;

}
```

but i get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
                java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
                java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
                loadRules(ControllerDrools.java:48)
```

which is this line

```
Reader source = new InputStreamReader(ControllerDrools.class.getResourceAsStream(rulesPath));
```

Any body knows how to read this rules ? Where to put them ?

Thank you very much for reading this, it means a lot to me.

Comment: some debugging might help here to check for NPE.

Comment: Can you omit /WEB-INF/ from path and then try? Use path like "rules/ZatraziTrening.drl".

Comment: tried it, still the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ControllerDrools.class.getResourceAsStream(rulesPath), your path should be **relative** from your ControllerDrools class package.

To make your path **absolute**, you should add a leading slash "/rules/ZatraziTrening.drl"

You can also use the following syntax to have absolute path :

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(rulesPath)
```

If you use maven, i advise you to put drl files directly in "src/main/resources"

Comment: not using maven :/ if you mean this code to use
    Reader source = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(rulesPath));
with this path:
"/rules/ZatraziTrening.drl";

same problem.

tnx for responding.

Comment: Could you try to put your drl directly with your code. So that, we will be sure it's in the classpath. Then access it like that this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/myproject/ZatraziTrening.drl")

Comment: path to drl files: src\fon\tastic\runner\expertSystem
code: Reader source = new InputStreamReader(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fon/tastic/runner/expertSystem/ZatraziTrening.drl"));
still null pointer exception.

Comment: It's strange. To be sure that your drl are in the class path, put it in "WEB_INF/lib/fon/tast‌​ic/runner/expertSystem/ZatraziTrening.drl". Then try to access it like that Reader source = new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("fon/tast‌​ic/runner/expertSystem/ZatraziTrening.drl"));